# PHP HTML Auto Complete / Snippet VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know if a VS code extension exists that auto completes PHP while outside of a `<?php ?>` tag. For example when I use Sublime Text 3 if I start typing "if" outside of a `<?php ?>` tag an autocomplete/snippet would insert the following: `<?php if (condition): ?> HTML Code Here <?php endif ?>`. See example bellow.

```
<div>Some text</div>
<!-- If I were to start typing "if" here I would get an autocomplete popup that inserts the IF statement snippet bellow -->
<?php if (condition): ?>
    HTML Goes Here  
<?php endif ?>
<div>Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enable html support in any language by adding the following to your **settings.json** file:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "your-language": "html",
    "rust": "html",
    "php": "html",
    "javascript": "html",
}
```